# Error when loading textarea fields in CP after upgrade Undefined index: field_fmt_options

Tags: error, textarea

Only happens on a couple textarea fields, not all.  I can still edit the fields but only after scrolling past all these error messages...

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: field_fmt_options
Filename: fieldtypes/EE_Fieldtype.php
Line Number: 562

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
Line Number: 324

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: field_fmt_options
Filename: fieldtypes/EE_Fieldtype.php
Line Number: 562

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
Line Number: 324

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: field_fmt_options
Filename: fieldtypes/EE_Fieldtype.php
Line Number: 562

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
Line Number: 324

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: field_fmt_options
Filename: fieldtypes/EE_Fieldtype.php
Line Number: 562

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
Line Number: 324

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: field_fmt_options
Filename: fieldtypes/EE_Fieldtype.php
Line Number: 562

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
Line Number: 324

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: field_fmt_options
Filename: fieldtypes/EE_Fieldtype.php
Line Number: 562

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
Line Number: 324
```

I have re-uploaded all the files for EE and Addons in use.  I am running EE 2.10.1 and all  the latest versions of FreeformPro, Playa, Matrix and Wygwam.

Answer (score 1):

Just uploading the new files for modules doesn't complete the modules upgrade.
You need to hit the "Run Module Updates" button on the Modules page.

I like to delete an addon's folder and upload the new files fresh without overwriting an existing folder as this can sometimes cause inconsistancies and obsolete files linger behind.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  I did do those things, run module update and delete old addon folders before uploading new and no luck.

I did find the issue though, I noticed that the Default Text Formatting for the texteara field had no Field Formatting options in the drop down, I had to click Edit Options and check Yes to enable options like Auto BR/ and XHTML.

Strange that those would all be disabled.  Thank you.